# Adding tabindex to dynamic elements

Tags: jquery

I have a form with fields some of which could be hidden. For proper accessibility I add tabindex with jQuery, only to those elements that are currently visible:

```
$(':input:visible').each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1);
});
```

It works great. However when I decided to add a tabindex to a span with a specific class name, that element is being skipped. Why?

```
$(':input:visible, .tabIn').each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1);
});

<span class="tabIn">my span</span>
```

Comment: Being skipped? It doens't get a tabindex at all?

Comment: In HTML5 every tag can have a tabindex.

Comment: Yes, no tabindex is added. However, if I add it manually, tabbing works great. Is there a syntax error in my jQuery function?.. makes no sense

Comment: non-repro http://jsfiddle.net/kLh6u/

Comment: Do you have a bit more code to look at? There is no syntax error in your jQuery. And it is a HTML5 page right?

Comment: OK, the code is correct then... Must be something else that's causing the problem.... :( #Zeaklous what do you mean by propagation issue? What shall I look for?

Comment: No it's not HTML5. Why would that matter?

Comment: Do you affect spans anywhere else in your code? I mean I had issues with this line `$('body:not(.tab, .content)').click(function() { ` before I had to stop the propagation of certain other clicks affecting `.tab` and `.content`

Comment: No, nothing like that. I've tried moving that class name into wrapping div and still nothing.

Comment: I've placed tabindex into the span manually to test -- works great.

Comment: OK, totally my fault. My JS was sitting in a conditional part of code and was not available... need more caffeine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works correct for me :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(':input:visible, .tabIn').each(function (i) {
                $(this).css('background-color','red').attr('tabindex', i + 1);
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span class="tabIn">my span</span>

    <input name="tabIn" />
    </body>
</html>
```